# Using Etsy API, how to get variation-images in listing

Tags: api, etsy

I'm using `listings` api to get listings, inventory and variations in one shot:

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/123456789?includes=Inventory,Images,MainImage,Variations,Attributes&api_key=XXXXXXXXX
```

And I would like in addition the relation between `variations` and `images`.

So for that point, the `variation-images` api is fine:

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/123456789/variation-images?api_key=XXXXXXXXX
```

This give me back the following associations : `(property_id, value_id, image_id)` !

But now when I try to get all-in-one (adding `VariationImage` to `?includes`) :

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/123456789?includes=Inventory,Images,MainImage,Variations,Attributes,VariationImage&api_key=XXXXXXXXX
```

I get a 400 response:`Model ShopListing has no association named VariationImage`

however this association is present in [the list of possible associations](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listing#section_associations) of the official documentation.

Do you have a tip to get this relation in one shot ?